# How to get suggestions on Google Docs with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57269847) StackOverflow answer that says "You can get the suggestions made in a document doing a get request," but when I follow the link I see Java and Python options. How can I actually get suggestions using exclusively Google Apps Script? I don't need to modify them at all, just get their existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Docs` service of Apps Script and access the data you need to have based on its response.

#### Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var documentId = <document ID>;
  var doc = Docs.Documents.get(documentId);
  doc.body.content.forEach(function (content){
    if (content.paragraph) {
      var elements = content.paragraph.elements;
      elements.forEach(function (element){
        if(element.textRun.suggestedDeletionIds)
          Logger.log("suggested to delete: " + element.textRun.content)
        if(element.textRun.suggestedInsertionIds)
          Logger.log("suggested to insert: " + element.textRun.content)
      });
    }
  });
}
```

#### Sample Data:

[image: sample]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Reference:

- https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60776585/16132436

Comment: Error trying to save this code in editor: Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' line: 2 file: ag1.gs

Comment: @Cooper, replace `<document ID>` with the actual document id of the doc file.